# sou novo na programação sera que você pode me ajudar?

Tags: python, if

gostaria que o resultado dos IFs entrassem direto na variável (lista2) e fossem printados todos os números exemplo [1,3,2,5,5,7,8]. Meu código ate agora:

```
lista = []
lista2 = []
while len(lista)+1 <= 7:
 lista.append(int(input("Digite o valor: ")))
print ((lista))

    if lista[0]==lista[1]:
     lista2 = lista[0] + lista[1] 

    if lista[1]==lista[2]:
     lista2 = lista[1] + lista[2]

    if lista[2]==lista[3]:
     lista2 = lista[2] + lista[3]

    if lista[3]==lista[4]:
     lista2 = lista[3] + lista[4]

    if lista[4]==lista[5]:
     lista2 = lista[4] + lista[5]

    if lista[5]==lista[6]:
     lista2 = lista[5] + lista[6]

print(lista2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do jeito que está o seu código a variável lista2 não é do tipo lista, pois você está atribuindo uma soma de dois int nela, então ela será int, e além disso se `lista[0] == lista[1]` e `lista[2] == lista[3]` a variável lista2 só pegará o último valor, já que está sobrescrevendo ela, caso queira criar uma lista com os números iguais você tem que colocar
`lista2.append(lista[0]+lista[1])`

Outra coisa é que você não precisa fazer esse tanto de if, já que segue um padrão você pode colocar num for

```
for i in range(1,len(lista)):
  if lista[i-1]==lista[i]:
    lista2.append(lista[i-1]+lista[i])
```

o python também te permite soluções mais sofisticadas, como:

```
lista2 = [lista[i-1]+lista[i] for i in range(1,len(lista)) if lista[i-1]==lista[i]]
```

Comment: obg pela dica ajudou muito